# Prove that $\dim range T = 1$ if and only if there is a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ all entries of $M(T)$ equal $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional and $T \in L(V,W)$ . Prove that $\dim range T = 1$ if and only if there is a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that with respect to these bases , all entries of $M(T)$ equal $1$.

proof: Conversely suppose there is a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that with respect to these bases , all entries of $M(T)$ equal $1$.

Then let $v_1,...,v_m$ and $w_1,...,w_n$ be basis of $V$ and $W$. And define a unique linear map $T: V →W$ by $Tv_i = w_i $ for $1 \leq i \leq m$.

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional and $T \in L(V,W)$ .
And let  $\dim range T = 1$. Then $\dim null T = \dim V -1$. Let $u_1,...,u_m $ be a basis of null$T$. Thus dim null $T$ = $m.$

Can someone please help? I am stuck.Thank you!

Comment: What is $M(T)$?

Comment: M(T) is the matrix of the linear map T. with respect to the bases of V and W. and it's  an m x n matrix

Comment: One direction: Suppose there exists a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ such that w.r.t. to these bases, the matrix $M(T)$ has all ones. The column space of $M(T)$ is spanned by the all-ones vector, so the range of $T$ is $\operatorname{span}\{w_1+\cdots+w_n\}$, which is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

I am reading "[Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition](https://linear.axler.net/)" by Sheldon Axler.
This exercise is Exercise 3C.2 on p.79 in this book.
I solved this exercise as follows:

Let $m:=\dim V$.
Let $n:=\dim W$.
Then, by Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps on p.62, $$\dim\operatorname{null}T=\dim V-\dim\operatorname{range}T=m-1.$$
Let $v_2,\dots,v_m$ be a basis of $\operatorname{null}T$.
Let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m$ be a basis of $V$.

Then, $v_1,v_2+v_1,\dots,v_m+v_1$ is linearly independent:
Proof:
Let $a_1v_1+a_2(v_2+v_1)+\dots+a_m(v_m+v_1)=0$.
Then, $(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_m)v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_mv_m=0$.
Then, $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_m=a_2=\dots=a_m=0$ since $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m$ is linearly independent.
Then, $a_2=\dots=a_m=0$ and $a_1=-(a_2+\dots+a_m)=-(0+\dots+0)=-0=0$.
So, $v_1,v_2+v_1,\dots,v_m+v_1$ is linearly independent.

So, $v_1,v_2+v_1,\dots,v_m+v_1$ is a basis of $V$.
Since $v_2,\dots,v_m\in\operatorname{null}T$, $Tv_2=\dots=Tv_m=0$.
So, $Tv_1=T(v_2+v_1)=\dots=T(v_m+v_1)$.
Since $\dim\operatorname{range}T=1$, $T\neq 0$.
So, $Tv_1=T(v_2+v_1)=\dots=T(v_m+v_1)\neq 0$.

Let $w_1:=Tv_1$.
Let $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$ be a basis of $W$.

Then, $w_1-w_2-\dots-w_n,w_2,\dots,w_n$ is linearly independent:
Proof:
Let $b_1(w_1-w_2-\dots-w_n)+b_2w_2+\dots+b_nw_n=0$.
Then, $b_1w_1+(b_2-b_1)w_2+\dots+(b_n-b_1)w_n=0$.
Then, $b_1=b_2-b_1=\dots=b_n-b_1=0$ since $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$ is linearly independent.
Then, $b_1=0$ and $b_2=\dots=b_n=b_1=0$.
So, $w_1-w_2-\dots-w_n,w_2,\dots,w_n$ is linearly independent.

So, $w_1-w_2-\dots-w_n,w_2,\dots,w_n$ is a basis of $W$.

Then,
$Tv_1=w_1=1(w_1-w_2-\dots-w_n)+1w_2+\dots+1w_n$.
$T(v_2+v_1)=Tv_1=1(w_1-w_2-\dots-w_n)+1w_2+\dots+1w_n$.
$\dots$
$T(v_m+v_1)=Tv_1=1(w_1-w_2-\dots-w_n)+1w_2+\dots+1w_n$.

So, there exist a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that with respect to these bases, all entries of $\mathcal{M}(T)$ equal $1$.

---

---

Paul Ash, thank you very much for your comments.

I rewrite my answer as follows:

---

> My small lemma:
> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space.
> Let $m:=\dim V$.
> Let $v_1,\dots,v_m$ be a basis of $V$.
> Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$.
> Let $i,j\in\{1,\dots, m\}$ such that $i\neq j$.
> Then the list $u_1,\dots,u_m$ such that $u_k:=v_k$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}\setminus\{i\}$ and $u_i:=v_i+bv_j$ is also a basis of $V$.

Proof:
Let $a_1u_1+\cdots+a_iu_i+\cdots+a_mu_m=0$.
Then, $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_i(v_i+bv_j)+\cdots+a_mv_m=0$.
Then, $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_iv_i+\cdots+(a_j+a_ib)v_j+\cdots+a_mv_m=0$ if $i<j$ and $a_1v_1+\cdots+(a_j+a_ib)v_j+\cdots++a_iv_i+\cdots+a_mv_m=0$ if $j<i$.
Since $v_1,\dots,v_m$ is linearly independent, $a_k=0$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}\setminus\{j\}$ and $a_j+a_ib=0$.
Since $a_i=0$ and $a_j+a_ib=0$, $a_j=-a_ib=-0\cdot b=0$.
So, $u_1,\dots,u_m$ is linearly independent and is a basis of $V$.

---

(1)
Let $m:=\dim V$.
Let $n:=\dim W$.
Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$.
Let $v_1,\dots,v_m$ be a basis of $V$.
Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$.
Let $i,j\in\{1,\dots, m\}$ such that $i\neq j$.
Let $u_1,\dots,u_m$ be the list such that $u_k:=v_k$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}\setminus\{i\}$ and $u_i:=v_i+bv_j$.
Then, $u_1,\dots,u_m$ is a basis of $V$ by the above lemma.
Let $w_1,\dots,w_n$ be a basis of $W$.
Let $\mathcal{M}(T,(v_1,\dots,v_m),(w_1,\dots,w_n))=\pmatrix{A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,m}\\\vdots & & \vdots\\A_{n,1} & \cdots & A_{n,m}}$.
Then, $\mathcal{M}(T,(u_1,\dots,u_m),(w_1,\dots,w_n))=
\pmatrix{
A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,i}+bA_{1,j} & \cdots & A_{1,m}\\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
A_{n,1} & \cdots & A_{n,i}+bA_{n,j} & \cdots & A_{n,m}
}$.

---

(2)
Let $m:=\dim V$.
Let $n:=\dim W$.
Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$.
Let $v_1,\dots,v_m$ be a basis of $V$.
Let $w_1,\dots,w_n$ be a basis of $W$.
Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$.
Let $i,j\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ such that $i\neq j$.
Let $y_1,\dots,y_n$ be the list such that $y_k:=w_k$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{i\}$ and $y_i:=w_i-bw_j$.
Then, $y_1,\dots,y_n$ is a basis of $W$ by the above lemma.
Let $\mathcal{M}(T,(v_1,\dots,v_m),(w_1,\dots,w_n))=\pmatrix{A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,m}\\\vdots & & \vdots\\A_{n,1} & \cdots & A_{n,m}}$.
Then, $\mathcal{M}(T,(v_1,\dots,v_m),(y_1,\dots,y_n))=
\pmatrix{
A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
A_{j,1}+bA_{i,1} & \cdots & A_{j,m}+bA_{i,m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
A_{n,1} & \cdots & A_{n,m}
}$.

---

Let $m:=\dim V$.
Let $n:=\dim W$.
Then, by Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps on p.62, $$\dim\operatorname{null}T=\dim V-\dim\operatorname{range}T=m-1.$$
Let $v_2,\dots,v_m$ be a basis of $\operatorname{null}T$.
Let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m$ be a basis of $V$.
Since $\dim\operatorname{range}T=1$, $T\neq 0$.
So, $Tv_1\neq 0$.
Let $w_1:=Tv_1$.
Let $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$ be a basis of $W$.
Then, $\mathcal{M}(T,(v_1,\dots,v_m),(w_1,\dots,w_n))=\pmatrix{1 & \cdots & 0\\\vdots & & \vdots\\0 & \cdots & 0}$.

By the operations in (1) and (2) above, we can construct a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that with respect to these bases, all entries of $\mathcal{M}(T)$ equal $1$.

Comment: Why can we let $w_1 := Tv_1$?

Comment: @PaulAsh By Theorem 2.32 on p.41 in "Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition (https://linear.axler.net/)",  every linearly independent list extends to a basis. $w_1:=Tv_1$ is not $0$. So the list $w_1$ is a linearly independent list of length $1$. So, the list $w_1$ extends to a basis $w_1, w_2,\dots, w_n$ of $W$.

Comment: @佐武五郎 got it, thanks. But what's the intuition of the bases that was chosen? How would I know in advance that choosing $v_1, v_2+v_1, \ldots, v_m + v_1$ as a basis of $V$ and choosing $w_1 - w_2 - \cdots - w_n, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ as a basis of $W$ would lead me to the matrix of $T$ having all coefficients be $1$?

Comment: @PaulAsh I edited my answer. Please see my answer. Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{ v_1 , \ldots ,v_n\}$ be an arbitrary basis of $V$ and $w \in W$ a generator of $range(T)$. Without loss of generality $T v_i = \lambda_i w$ with $\lambda_i \neq 0$  (as for example you can replace all $v_i$ with $v_i + v$ where $T v = w$).

Write $w = a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_mw_m$ as a linear combination of some basis such that $a_i \neq 0$ for each $i = 1,\ldots , m$.

Then, take $\mathcal{B}_V = \{ \frac{v_1}{\lambda_1} , \cdots , \frac{v_n}{\lambda_n}\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_W = \{a_1w_1 , \cdots, a_mw_m\}$.