# Prove that $dim$ $range$ $T=1$ if and only if there is a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ all entries of $M(T)$ equal $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T∈L(V,W)$ . Prove that
> $dim$ $range$ $T=1$ if and only if there is a basis of $V$ and a basis
> of $W$ such that with respect to these bases, all entries of $M(T)$
> equal $1$.

The proof from the side of the matrix $M(T)$ with entries of one is easy. You just need to define $T v_i = w_1+...+w_n$ and see that $range T = span(w_1+...+w_n)$.

**(1)** When I try to prove from the other side, that means "assume $dim$ $range$ $T=1$". Why can't I just assume some $T$, for example, $T v_i = w_1+...+w_n$, and then it is obvious to see that nothing prevents this $T$ from existing and all the entries of the matrix are 1.

I'm reading this answer to the question: [Prove that $\dim range T = 1$ if and only if there is a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ all entries of $M(T)$ equal $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945925/prove-that-dim-range-t-1-if-and-only-if-there-is-a-basis-of-v-and-a-basis)
and **(2)** I don't understand why they did such a long way to prove the second way and assume it is necessary, **(3)** how the heck did they think about this way, I mean, how did they think "Lets set $v_1,v_2+v_1,…,v_m+v_1$, it might be somehow beneficial for solving the question in the future".

It seems like this kind of intuition is not developed in me. It seems to me that they just somehow reached this arbitrary basis and it helped them reach the answer. but... how?

Comment: What exactly is the equation $T_{vi} = w_1+...+w_n$ supposed to mean? Should that be $T v_i$?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "just assume some $T$"? The point is that this statement is supposed to hold for *every* $T$ for which the dimension of the range is $1$. If you stipulate that this $T$ is also one for which $T v_i = w_1 + \cdots + w_n$, then we can't be sure that we are proving the result for all of the transformations $T$ for which the result is supposed to hold.

Comment: I think that the proof could be a bit more intuitively presented in terms of row/column operations, but that version of the proof would take longer to write out.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I changed it to $Tvi$, you are right.
This line got me to understand it "The point is that this statement is supposed to hold for every $T$ for which the dimension of the range is 1". I should find those bases that no matter what T there is, the statement will be correct. Thank you :)